# Sending a message to set of hosts with acknowledgements

Tags: go, rpc

Function is like:

```
func Message(worker_ID int, message string, args *Args , reply *int) chan bool {
}
```

This function resides at host which is called by client when it want to send the message to hosts, hosts are located at different place, so both IP and port required to send message right? which mechanism can be helpful `net.dial()` or `gob` or `rpc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//server.go will provide the interface for communicating and handling hosts

// workerDead(message string), send the message and wait for ack, if no ack means worker dead

```
package
main
import(

"fmt"
"io"
"net"
"net/http"
"net/rpc"
"path"
"os"
)

type Flag int
type Args struct{
message string
}
func main() {

flag := new(Flag)
rpc.Register(flag)
rpc.HandleHTTP()
err := http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil) //ListenAndServe starts an HTTP server with a given address and handler.
//The handler is usually nil, which means to use DefaultServeMux.
if err != nil {
fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
}

//Worker counts the number of hosts
func workerCount() int
{
return db.runCommand( { count: 'id' } ) //mongodb command to count the id
}

// Returns an array of the distinct values of field id from all documents in the workers collection
//In mongodb document is analogous to rdbms table and collection is record

func Worker(worker int) []string{
return db.runCommand ({ distinct: 'workers', key: 'id' } ) //mongodb command to get the array of list of
//workers for column id
}

func Message(worker int, message string, args *Args , reply *int) chan bool {


server, err :=rpc.Dial("tcp","192.168.23.12") //Serve Dials here to send message to host, IP address here is of host
if(err!=nil){
log.Fatal("Dialing", err)
}
var reply bool
args:=Args{message};
err = server.Call(args,&reply);
if(err!=nil){
log.Fatal("Dialing", err)
replaceWorker(); // No reply from worker then call to replace worker
}
fmt.Println("Reply from host", reply);

}
return nil
}
//Replace dead worker of particular project with fresh worker
func replaceWorker(worker_id int,project_id int)
{
db.workers.update( //this query updates workers collection with id=worker_id(id of dead worker)
   { _id: worker_id, _project_id: project_id },
   {
     //$set: { ' ': 'Warner' },
   }

)

}
```

Comment: It really helps readability if you indent your code, especially with a language like go

Answer (score 2):

If you want something simple then check out [net/rpc](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/) which wraps gob and networking into a remote procedure call framework which should do what you want.

**Server**

From the docs a server running over HTTP

```
type Args struct {
        A, B int
}

type Arith int

func (t *Arith) Multiply(args *Args, reply *int) error {
        *reply = args.A * args.B
        return nil
}

arith := new(Arith)
rpc.Register(arith)
rpc.HandleHTTP()
l, e := net.Listen("tcp", ":1234")
if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen error:", e)
}
go http.Serve(l, nil)
```

**Client**

At this point, clients can see a service "Arith" with method "Arith.Multiply". To invoke one, dial the server then make a call.  You can also make asynchronous calls where the result comes back in a channel.

```
client, err := rpc.DialHTTP("tcp", serverAddress + ":1234")
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dialing:", err)
}

args := &server.Args{7,8}
var reply int
err = client.Call("Arith.Multiply", args, &reply)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("arith error:", err)
}
fmt.Printf("Arith: %d*%d=%d", args.A, args.B, reply)
```

A slight oddity of the framework is that each remote call can have only one input argument and one output argument which means that you need to wrap all your arguments in a `struct`.

Comment: Yeah thanks buddy, I saw this in Go networking doc. But I am not getting that as I have set of host located at different place, how can I send them message using this as there's not specification of remote host's IP here...

Comment: The simplest thing would be to keep a note of the remote host IPs in your program. You can find the IP address of each server by logging into it and using `ifconfig` (linux) or `ipconfig` (windows).  You then stuff the IP address you find into `serverAddress` above.

Comment: Yeah I have IP of both server and host, but suppose host having IP 192.168.12.4 then how server can send message to host? where this ip should be placed by server to send message in above code?

Comment: You have two choices.  You can make the clients poll for messages on the server, or you can run the server code on the clients as well so the server can send messages to the client.

Comment: @KarimkhanPathan, when you have a TCP connection (a client connected to the server) you already have a two-way communication channel, so the connected client by definition knows where to send its ACK - to its existing connection. So I'd just keep clients connected and implemented a wire protocol over TCP (using gob for instance).

Comment: If you remember there are 3 entity here, Client,server and host! When client want to send message to host it will call above function, and as server has database it will fetch it's required info like IP and forward message to host sent by client...
@kosix and Nick: will this work???

Comment: Sounds like that could work!  The server is acting as a proxy for the host effectively.

Comment: I am on way and reached at :

Comment: I am on way and reached at :
package main
import()
type Flag int
type Args struct{
message string
}
func main() {
flag := new(Flag)
rpc.Register(flag)
rpc.HandleHTTP()
err := http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil) 
if err != nil {
fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
}
func Message(worker int, message string, args *Args , reply *int) chan bool {
server, err :=rpc.Dial("tcp","192.16.2.2")
if(err!=nil){
log.Fatal("Dialing", err)
}
var reply bool
args:=Args{message};
err = server.Call(args,&reply);
if(err!=nil){
log.Fatal("Dialing", err)
replaceWorker();
}
fmt.Println("Reply from host", reply);

}
return nil
}